# How to animate wthout stop with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a h1 move forward and backward slowly without stop on page load.
What I got now is this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#presentation-container h1").animate({
        opacity:'1',
        marginLeft:'+=600px',
    }, 1300);
});
```

to make the h1 slide on start.

How to make it animate slowly forward and backwards without stop?

Comment: I want to ask why, but I'm dreading the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function moveRight() {
        $("div#presentation-container h1").animate({
            opacity:'1',
            marginLeft:'+=600px',
        }, 1300, moveLeft);
    }

    function moveLeft() {
        $("div#presentation-container h1").animate({
            opacity:'1',
            marginLeft:'-=600px',
        }, 1300, moveRight);
    }

    moveRight();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is more similar to the result I wish to get :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#presentation-container h1").animate({
        opacity:'1',
        marginLeft:'+=600px',
    }, 1300).animate({
        opacity:'1',
        marginLeft:'-=600px',
    }, 1300);
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken, this will move it right, then left, then stop. OP wants it to move forever.

Comment: Put what's in the ready function in a while(true) loop and you should be able to go on forever.

Comment: @MattB That'll crash the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this:

```
<marquee behaviour="alternate" speed="1"><h1>Text here</h1></marquee>
```

Optionally add `style="width:900px"` or similar to adjust the width of the scrolling area.

That said, it's an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but marquee is not what I mean, sorry

Comment: Why not? It does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: Also note that `<marquee>` has been deprecated in HTML5. However, it came back with CSS3. (Seriously, see the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee)

Comment: Nope, at first I want to make h1 slide out, then after sliding out I want to move it like a cloud, slowly :)